# Intern Async call in before()

Tags: javascript, node.js, testing, intern

I need to request some json files that contain data I use for testing.  I would like to make the request in the setup method, but there is no async method attached to it.  When I run the code below, the log inside the test login function gets sent to the console before my logs from the setup method get sent.  Is there a way I can tell setup to wait till my calls get completed before running the tests?

```
define([
  'intern!object',
  'pages/LoginPage',
  'data-objects/DataFetcher'
], function(registerSuite, LoginPage, DataFetcher) {

  registerSuite(function() {

    var loginId = admin;
    var password = test;
    var regionData = US;
    var loginPage = null;

    return {

        name: 'Login test',

        setup: function() {
            // Initialize page objects
            loginPage = new LoginPage(this.remote, this.timeout);

            // get test data
            DataFetcher.getData(Pages.LoginPage).then(function(response) {
                logger.info(DataFetcher.generateData(response));
            });

            DataFetcher.getData(Pages.TablePage).then(function(response) {
                logger.info(DataFetcher.generateData(response));
            });

            DataFetcher.getData(Pages.PersonPage).then(function(response) {
                logger.info(DataFetcher.generateData(response));
            });

            DataFetcher.getData(Pages.BasicInfoPage).then(function(response) {
                logger.info(DataFetcher.generateData(response));
            });

            DataFetcher.getData(Pages.CompanyInfoPage).then(function(response) {
                logger.info(DataFetcher.generateData(response));
            });
        },

        login: function() {
            logger.log('info', 'Login is ' + loginId + ' Password ' +
                password);
            return loginPage.load(regionData.BASE_URL)
                .login(loginId, password)
                .getAccumulatedState();
        }
    };
  });
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you return a Promise from the `setup` function, Intern will wait for it to resolve before starting tests. You can return a `Promise.all(...)` of all your requests.